# Can Eclipse format comma-separated statements (var a = 1, b=2;) on different lines?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdt

I am using Eclipse JSDT and the default formatting settings change something like

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2;
```

to be on one ugly line.

The style before formatting is recommended by JSLint, so I am wondering can Eclipse be set to format it this way? The existing formatter settings does not offer controls over the comma statement it seems.

Comment: Filed a workaround with Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=379114

Comment: Are you using Aptana or JSBeautifier?

Comment: Seems incredible that it's still unresolved...

Answer (score 1):

Following JavaScript Beautifier plug-in is available for Eclipse.

https://github.com/atlanto/eclipse-javascript-formatter

It can be used to span single statement - multiple variable declarations into multiple lines.

More information about using the above plug-in is given in the `README.md` file.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little late I guess, but I do this:

```
var container = require('../core/container'),
/**/uuid = require('node-uuid'),
/**/validations = require('../util/validations');
```

Or I do this:

```
var container = require('../core/container'), //
uuid = require('node-uuid'), //
validations = require('../util/validations');
```

The second one shifts the variables to the beginning of the line, but that's a trade off you'll have to live with.